# Lua Trigonometry

Tags: lua, latitude-longitude, bearing

Currently I am trying to get the bearing from the first latitude-longitude point to the last.

I have been to the movable-type website and have got my distance to work but my bearing seems to be giving me trouble.

```Lua
Y = math.sin(dLon_WPM_1) * math.cos(lat2_WPM_1)
X = math.cos(dLat_WPM_1) * math.sin(lat2_WPM_1) 
    - math.sin(dLat_WPM_1) * math.cos(lat2_WPM_1) * math.cos(dLon_WPM_1)
BRNG = math.deg(math.atan2(Y, X))
```

I have double checked and triple checked: all the values are the values I think they are.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the resulted BRNG? What is the expected BRNG? Are the input values correct? Is dLon calculated as lon2-lon1? Is dLat calculated as lat2-lat1?

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `dLat_WPM_1` in the calc for X, try using `lat1_WPM_1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the effect of spherical coordinates? The bearing you are attempting to calculate would only be correct if you had projected the points onto something like a (bearing preserving) [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) and then calculated the rhumbline bearing.

If you are, instead, interested in the initial great circle bearing, you can look at the blog posting at [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for the equations.